# PrepareToInstall timing

Tags: service, inno-setup

I'm using the PrepareToInstall event to stop and remove a service.
This works fine, no errors are thrown.

However SOMETIMES there seems to be a timing problem because SOMETIMES InnoSetup tells me that 'oscmaintenanceservice' is still running and asks whether it should close it.

I thought that if the API returns from the function to close and remove the service, the app should already be gone.

Does anybody see any mistake on my side or has any suggestions for me?

Thank you!

```
function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;
begin

    //MsgBox('ssInstall.', mbInformation, MB_OK);

   if IsServiceInstalled('oscmaintenanceservice') then
   BEGIN
       //MsgBox('ssInstall: Service is installed.', mbInformation, MB_OK);

       if IsServiceRunning('oscmaintenanceservice') then
           BEGIN
               //MsgBox('ssInstall: Service is running.', mbInformation, MB_OK);

               if not StopService('oscmaintenanceservice') then
               BEGIN
                   MsgBox('ssInstall: Couldnt stop service.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
               END
           else
           BEGIN
               //MsgBox('ssInstall: Service was stopped.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
           END;
       END
           else
           BEGIN
               MsgBox('ssInstall: Service not running.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
           END;
       if not RemoveService('oscmaintenanceservice') then
           BEGIN
               MsgBox('ssInstall: Couldnt remove service.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
           END
           else
           BEGIN
               //MsgBox('ssInstall: Service was removed', mbInformation, MB_OK);
           END;
   END
   else
   BEGIN
       MsgBox('ssInstall: Service not installed.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
   END;
END;
```

Comment: You question has nothing to do with `PrepareToInstall`. It's about the implementation of the functions you are calling. And we do not know what these are doing.

Comment: Also, what does it mean *"InnoSetup tells me that 'oscmaintenanceservice' is still running"*?

Comment: Installer log file may help too (use `/log` command-line switch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Windows need a little time to recognize the service has been removed.

I have added sleep(1000) after the stopping and remove function in PrepareToInstall, and since then it works fine.